Next 14 hydration error when using custom isMobile hook
For a long time, I've been using a custom react hook called useIsMobile that returns true if the viewport is under a specific width. I used this hook in all my projects and I never had an issue with it.
Recentlly I started a new project using Next 14 and I started to get this error:
Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML. See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
After some debugging, I realize that the issue is with my custom hook. When I'm using the hook, the server sends the "mobile version" first but the client renders the "desktop version" as it should and creates a difference between the react tree that was pre-rendered from the server and the react tree that was rendered during the first render.
This issue persists even if I use 'use client'.
I've also noticed that occasionally, the error can be triggered by CSS media queries, or they might be outright ignored.
Did anyone else encounter this issue? Does anyone know how I can fix this?
This is the hook that I use:
'use client';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useWindowSize = () => {
  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState({
    width: typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window?.innerWidth : null,
    height: typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window?.innerHeight : null,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        setWindowSize({
          width: window?.innerWidth,
          height: window?.innerHeight,
        });
      }
    };

    window?.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

    handleResize();

    return () => window?.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, []);

  return windowSize;
};

export default useWindowSize;

'use client';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import useWindowSize from './useWindowSize';

const useIsMobile = (breakpoint: number = 768): boolean => {
  const { width } = useWindowSize()!;
  const [isMobile, setMobile] = useState<boolean>(
    width! <= (breakpoint || 768)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    setMobile(width! <= (breakpoint || 768));
  }, [width, breakpoint]);

  return isMobile;
};

export default useIsMobile;

  const isMobile = useIsMobile(500);

  return (
    <div className={styles.nav}>
      {!isMobile && <div className={styles.logo}>Logo</div>}


A solution is to hold rendering the element until the client-side evaluation the device width.
'use client';
import { useState, useEffect, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import useWindowSize from './useWindowSize';

const useIsMobile = (breakpoint = 768) => {
  const { width } = useWindowSize();
  const [isMobile, setMobile] = useState(null);  // starts as null to indicate no initial assumption

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (width !== null) {
      setMobile(width <= breakpoint);
    }
  }, [width, breakpoint]);

  return isMobile;
};

export default useIsMobile;

In your component, you can then conditionally render content based on whether isMobile has been determined:
const isMobile = useIsMobile(500);

if (isMobile === null) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
}

return (
  <div className={styles.nav}>
    {!isMobile && <div className={styles.logo}>Logo</div>}
  </div>
);

